# xml attributes in php is not working

Tags: php, xml

### smiley_xml_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
<row><navnelbnr>552428</navnelbnr><cvrnr>34983437</cvrnr><pnr>1018366998</pnr><region /><brancheKode>47.29.00.A</brancheKode><branche>Apoteker, materialister, helsekostforretninger mv., ikke-let</branche><virksomhedstype>Detail</virksomhedstype><navn1>Aloe Vera Butik Amager </navn1><adresse1>Jansvej 76</adresse1><postnr>2300</postnr><By>København S</By><seneste_kontrol /><seneste_kontrol_dato /><naestseneste_kontrol /><naestseneste_kontrol_dato /><tredjeseneste_kontrol /><tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato /><fjerdeseneste_kontrol /><fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato /><URL>http://www.findsmiley.dk/da-DK/Searching/DetailsView.htm?virk=552428</URL><reklame_beskyttelse>0</reklame_beskyttelse><Elite_Smiley>2</Elite_Smiley><Kaedenavn /><Geo_Lng>12.620085</Geo_Lng><Geo_Lat>55.640269</Geo_Lat><Pixibranche>Apoteker og materialister</Pixibranche></row>
<row><navnelbnr>658802</navnelbnr><cvrnr>37686530</cvrnr><pnr>1021422432</pnr><region /><brancheKode>56.10.00.A</brancheKode><branche>Servering: Restauranter mv</branche><virksomhedstype>Detail</virksomhedstype><navn1>Katé's Café &amp; Grill </navn1><adresse1>Højby Stationsvej 8</adresse1><postnr>4573</postnr><By>Højby</By><seneste_kontrol>1</seneste_kontrol><seneste_kontrol_dato>13-07-2016 00:00:00</seneste_kontrol_dato><naestseneste_kontrol>2</naestseneste_kontrol><naestseneste_kontrol_dato>06-07-2016 00:00:00</naestseneste_kontrol_dato><tredjeseneste_kontrol /><tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato /><fjerdeseneste_kontrol /><fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato /><URL>http://www.findsmiley.dk/da-DK/Searching/DetailsView.htm?virk=658802</URL><reklame_beskyttelse>0</reklame_beskyttelse><Elite_Smiley>0</Elite_Smiley><Kaedenavn /><Geo_Lng>11.600316</Geo_Lng><Geo_Lat>55.909746</Geo_Lat><Pixibranche>Restauranter, pizzeriaer, kantiner m.m.</Pixibranche></row>
<row><navnelbnr>530158</navnelbnr><cvrnr>11259979</cvrnr><pnr>1003258332</pnr><region /><brancheKode>56.29.00.A</brancheKode><branche>Servering: Kantiner mv., fast personkreds over 12 personer</branche><virksomhedstype>Detail</virksomhedstype><navn1>Kastanjehaven 4. afdelingskøkken</navn1><adresse1>Troels-Lunds Vej 25</adresse1><postnr>2000</postnr><By>Frederiksberg</By><seneste_kontrol>1</seneste_kontrol><seneste_kontrol_dato>11-03-2016 00:00:00</seneste_kontrol_dato><naestseneste_kontrol>2</naestseneste_kontrol><naestseneste_kontrol_dato>25-01-2016 00:00:00</naestseneste_kontrol_dato><tredjeseneste_kontrol>1</tredjeseneste_kontrol><tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato>22-05-2015 00:00:00</tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato><fjerdeseneste_kontrol>2</fjerdeseneste_kontrol><fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato>15-04-2015 00:00:00</fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato><URL>http://www.findsmiley.dk/da-DK/Searching/DetailsView.htm?virk=530158</URL><reklame_beskyttelse>0</reklame_beskyttelse><Elite_Smiley>0</Elite_Smiley><Kaedenavn /><Geo_Lng>12.500311</Geo_Lng><Geo_Lat>55.674644</Geo_Lat><Pixibranche>Restauranter, pizzeriaer, kantiner m.m.</Pixibranche></row>
<row><navnelbnr>125410</navnelbnr><cvrnr>19503046</cvrnr><pnr>1002900683</pnr><region /><brancheKode>56.29.00.A</brancheKode><branche>Servering: Kantiner mv., fast personkreds over 12 personer</branche><virksomhedstype>Detail</virksomhedstype><navn1>BC Catering Skanderborg A/S Kantine</navn1><adresse1>Niels Bohrs Vej 20, Stilling</adresse1><postnr>8660</postnr><By>Skanderborg</By><seneste_kontrol>1</seneste_kontrol><seneste_kontrol_dato>08-10-2014 00:00:00</seneste_kontrol_dato><naestseneste_kontrol>1</naestseneste_kontrol><naestseneste_kontrol_dato>10-10-2013 00:00:00</naestseneste_kontrol_dato><tredjeseneste_kontrol>1</tredjeseneste_kontrol><tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato>07-08-2012 00:00:00</tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato><fjerdeseneste_kontrol>1</fjerdeseneste_kontrol><fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato>15-09-2011 00:00:00</fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato><URL>http://www.findsmiley.dk/da-DK/Searching/DetailsView.htm?virk=125410</URL><reklame_beskyttelse>0</reklame_beskyttelse><Elite_Smiley>1</Elite_Smiley><Kaedenavn /><Geo_Lng>9.986561</Geo_Lng><Geo_Lat>56.067036</Geo_Lat><Pixibranche>Restauranter, pizzeriaer, kantiner m.m.</Pixibranche></row>
<row><navnelbnr>118352</navnelbnr><cvrnr>14406042</cvrnr><pnr>1021609796</pnr><region /><brancheKode>56.29.00.A</brancheKode><branche>Servering: Kantiner mv., fast personkreds over 12 personer</branche><virksomhedstype>Detail</virksomhedstype><navn1>Nordea kantine v/ISS Catering</navn1><adresse1>Vesterbrogade 8, 5</adresse1><postnr>1620</postnr><By>København V</By><seneste_kontrol>1</seneste_kontrol><seneste_kontrol_dato>11-03-2015 00:00:00</seneste_kontrol_dato><naestseneste_kontrol>1</naestseneste_kontrol><naestseneste_kontrol_dato>14-11-2013 00:00:00</naestseneste_kontrol_dato><tredjeseneste_kontrol>1</tredjeseneste_kontrol><tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato>20-01-2011 00:00:00</tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato><fjerdeseneste_kontrol>1</fjerdeseneste_kontrol><fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato>16-03-2010 00:00:00</fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato><URL>http://www.findsmiley.dk/da-DK/Searching/DetailsView.htm?virk=118352</URL><reklame_beskyttelse>0</reklame_beskyttelse><Elite_Smiley>1</Elite_Smiley><Kaedenavn /><Geo_Lng>12.561447</Geo_Lng><Geo_Lat>55.673805</Geo_Lat><Pixibranche>Restauranter, pizzeriaer, kantiner m.m.</Pixibranche></row>
<row><navnelbnr>565829</navnelbnr><cvrnr>25360931</cvrnr><pnr>1018950037</pnr><region /><brancheKode>56.10.00.C</brancheKode><branche>Servering: Restauranter mv. - åbent op til 6 måneder om året</branche><virksomhedstype>Detail</virksomhedstype><navn1>Cafe Botanisk Have Bil 2</navn1><adresse1>Øster Farimagsgade 2</adresse1><postnr>1353</postnr><By>København K</By><seneste_kontrol>1</seneste_kontrol><seneste_kontrol_dato>03-08-2015 00:00:00</seneste_kontrol_dato><naestseneste_kontrol /><naestseneste_kontrol_dato /><tredjeseneste_kontrol /><tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato /><fjerdeseneste_kontrol /><fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato /><URL>http://www.findsmiley.dk/da-DK/Searching/DetailsView.htm?virk=565829</URL><reklame_beskyttelse>0</reklame_beskyttelse><Elite_Smiley>0</Elite_Smiley><Kaedenavn /><Geo_Lng>12.575363</Geo_Lng><Geo_Lat>55.690106</Geo_Lat><Pixibranche>Restauranter, pizzeriaer, kantiner m.m.</Pixibranche></row>
<row><navnelbnr>545126</navnelbnr><cvrnr>28025602</cvrnr><pnr>1019373408</pnr><region /><brancheKode>56.10.00.A</brancheKode><branche>Servering: Restauranter mv</branche><virksomhedstype>Detail</virksomhedstype><navn1>Figaros Pizza House </navn1><adresse1>Ourøgade 38</adresse1><postnr>2100</postnr><By>København Ø</By><seneste_kontrol>1</seneste_kontrol><seneste_kontrol_dato>02-09-2016 00:00:00</seneste_kontrol_dato><naestseneste_kontrol>1</naestseneste_kontrol><naestseneste_kontrol_dato>11-03-2016 00:00:00</naestseneste_kontrol_dato><tredjeseneste_kontrol>1</tredjeseneste_kontrol><tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato>02-09-2015 00:00:00</tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato><fjerdeseneste_kontrol>1</fjerdeseneste_kontrol><fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato>11-03-2015 00:00:00</fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato><URL>http://www.findsmiley.dk/da-DK/Searching/DetailsView.htm?virk=545126</URL><reklame_beskyttelse>0</reklame_beskyttelse><Elite_Smiley>1</Elite_Smiley><Kaedenavn /><Geo_Lng>12.568172</Geo_Lng><Geo_Lat>55.709702</Geo_Lat><Pixibranche>Restauranter, pizzeriaer, kantiner m.m.</Pixibranche></row>
<row><navnelbnr>71477</navnelbnr><cvrnr>36805110</cvrnr><pnr>1001749163</pnr><region /><brancheKode>56.29.00.A</brancheKode><branche>Servering: Kantiner mv., fast personkreds over 12 personer</branche><virksomhedstype>Detail</virksomhedstype><navn1>Beirholms Væverier A/S Kantinen</navn1><adresse1>Nordager 20</adresse1><postnr>6000</postnr><By>Kolding</By><seneste_kontrol>1</seneste_kontrol><seneste_kontrol_dato>10-04-2014 00:00:00</seneste_kontrol_dato><naestseneste_kontrol>1</naestseneste_kontrol><naestseneste_kontrol_dato>21-09-2012 00:00:00</naestseneste_kontrol_dato><tredjeseneste_kontrol>1</tredjeseneste_kontrol><tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato>22-08-2011 00:00:00</tredjeseneste_kontrol_dato><fjerdeseneste_kontrol>1</fjerdeseneste_kontrol><fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato>25-10-2010 00:00:00</fjerdeseneste_kontrol_dato><URL>http://www.findsmiley.dk/da-DK/Searching/DetailsView.htm?virk=71477</URL><reklame_beskyttelse>0</reklame_beskyttelse><Elite_Smiley>1</Elite_Smiley><Kaedenavn /><Geo_Lng>9.485146</Geo_Lng><Geo_Lat>55.546148</Geo_Lat><Pixibranche>Restauranter, pizzeriaer, kantiner m.m.</Pixibranche></row>
</document>
```

### get_xml_det.php

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("smiley_xml_test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

#echo "<pre>";print_r($xml->children());echo "</pre>"; 
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {

        $role = $child->attributes();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($role);echo "</pre>"; 
}

?>
```

here $role = $child->attributes(); is not working, please give some ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("smiley_xml_test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->row as $child) {        
        echo "<pre>";print_r($child->navnelbnr);echo "</pre>"; 
}
?>`

Comment: You have thrown in a lot of XML in there but I don't detect any attributes at all.

Comment: Its working now, thank you